# Ubuntu 15.04 on Windows 10 Hyper-V, hangs on 1st reboot

Tags: 15.04, virtualization, windows-10, hyper-v, squashfs

My Ubuntu 15.04 Hyper-V VM hangs on the first reboot after installation. FYI, I'm a complete Ubuntu beginner. This is the error line I get:

```
[791.989782] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 277588
[791.990009] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache entry [85d8f45]
[791.990024] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 85d8f45, size d16f
```

This is one example of the 3 different lines together but they keep repeating in this similar fashion.

Note: If I stop the VM and start again, everything appears fine although I'm not sure if it is?

Here is my VM config:

```
Gen 2 vhdx , dynamic
4GB - 8GB dynamic mem
4 proc
All integration services enabled
```

The host is Windows 10 Pro machine.

Is this anything to be concerned about?

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue, Un-checked  "Enable Dynamic Memory" and now it is working fine.

Comment: Exactly... Thanks a lot, voted up.

Comment: This fixed the same issue for my 18.04 installation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Having processor compatibility checked can also cause the problem.

Uncheck
Processor
-> Compatibility
-> Migrate to a physical computer with different processor version

Comment: Can you please add a bit more detail?